# How to delete an image located as URL in Flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, request

I am working in Flask-Python 3.x . I am developing a website where users can post with pictures in a public Forum. I am developing a link to erase posts. The view function associated with erasing a post is the following:

```
@main.route('/moderate-posts', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def moderate_posts():
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        post_to_remove = Post.query.filter_by(id=request.form["post_to_delete"]).first_or_404()
    # Remove image file if there is one in the post
        if post_to_remove.image_1_url is not None: 
            requests.delete(post_to_remove.image_1_url) # I found it out it doesn't make sense :( 
        Post.query.filter_by(id=post_to_remove.id).delete()
        db.session.commit()
        flash("The post has been deleted :) ")
    return render_template('moderate_posts.html', posts=posts)
```

I was trying to use `requests.delete(post_to_remove.image_1_url)` but it is not working.  The format of the `post_to_remove.image_1_url` is: `https://www.my_domain.org/static/img/img_posts/image.jpg` How can I remove the image of that post ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solve the question. In order to be able to use `os.remove(file_to_remove)` the first thing that is necessary to do is to locate the `file_to_remove` in the file system. The home path can be obtained in Python 3.4 with:

```
from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")
```

and in Python 3.5+ with:

```
from pathlib import Path
home = str(Path.home())
```

then:

```
if post_to_remove.image_1_url is not None:
    home = pathlib.Path(path.expanduser("~"))
    image_name = post_to_remove.image_1_url.split("/")[-1]
    file_to_remove = os.path.join(home,'/static/img/img_posts/', image_name)
    if os.path.isfile(file_to_remove):
        os.remove(file_to_remove)
    else:
        pass
```